# Remove icons from menu

Tags: 11.10, appmenu

After upgrading to 11.10 a couple of days ago, icons appeared in the menu. Now of course I want to get rid of them.

I searched on Google and it seems like they should have been there all the time but they first appeared after the upgrade, and for me it seems a bit overkill to have both icons and text. And I'm finding myself not being able to quickly find in the menus as before, strange eh.

So I read somewhere about these commands:

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_has_icons --type bool false
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons --type bool false
```

should remove them but it doesn't seem to work. Any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 3):

The command to disable menus with icons is:

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons --type bool false
```

The command to disable buttons with icons is the same as you note:

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons --type bool false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_has_icons
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons
```

Note that you may need to restart (at least log out and then in again) to see some of these changes.